# Galois Group Solution Check

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Find the Galois group $G = \text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\omega_{12})/\mathbb{Q})$, and its lattice of subgroups, where $\omega_{12}$ is the 12th root of unity.

We have that $$\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\omega_{12})/\mathbb{Q}) \cong (\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z})^{\times},$$ where $(\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ is the multiplicative group of units. And we know that the units of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ are the generators of $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})^{+}$. These are the elements that are coprime to 12. Therefore, $(\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z})^{\times} = \{1,5,7,11 \}$. The proper subgroups of $(\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ are $\{1 \}, \{1,5 \}, \{1,7 \}, \{1, 11 \}$.

The group $(\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z})^{\times}$ fixes $\mathbb{Q}$, $\{1,5\}$ fixes $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_{12}^5)$, $\{1,7 \}$ fixes $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_{12}^7)$, $\{1,11 \}$ fixes $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_{12}^{11})$ and $\{1 \}$ fixes $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_{12})$.

Also, is $\{1, \omega, \omega^2, ..., \omega^9, \omega^{10} \}$ a $\mathbb{Q}$ basis of $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_{12})$?

Comment: Please review a few things. The automorphism, call it $\sigma_n$ corresponding to residue class $\overline{n}\in\Bbb{Z}_{12}^*$ maps $\omega_{12}$ to $\omega_{12}^n$. In particular $\sigma_5(\omega_{12}^5)=(\omega_{12}^5)^5=\omega_{12}^{25}=\omega_{12}$. But $\omega_{12}\neq\omega_{12}^5$, so the subgroup generated by $\sigma_5$ **does not fix** $\Bbb{Q}(\omega_{12}^5)$.

Comment: Because $5$ is coprime to $12$, we have $\Bbb{Q}(\omega_{12})=\Bbb{Q}(\omega_{12}^5)$. Therefore only the trivial automorphism $\sigma_1$ fixes $\Bbb{Q}(\omega_{12}^5)$.

Comment: Re: Your last question. You already know that $\omega_{12}$ generates a Galois extension. For a Galois extension $L/K$ we always have $|G|=[L:K]$. You already know that $G$ has four elements. Therefore a $\Bbb{Q}$-basis of $\Bbb{Q}(\omega_{12})$ should also have four elements.

Comment: Finding the fixed fields is not always straightforward. Here basic facts about the Galois correspondence tell you that the fields corresponding to those three subgroups must all be quadratic (the groups have index two). In other words the fixed fields are of the form $\Bbb{Q}(\sqrt d)$ for some integer $d$. You need to use the fact that $\omega_{12}=\cos(\pi/6)+i\sin(\pi/6)=(\sqrt3+i)/2$. This will give you some kind of hints what subfields may be lurking in there.

Comment: Would the subfields be $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}), \mathbb{Q}(i),$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3}i)$? 

And, how would we choose a basis with only four elements? $\{1, \omega, \omega^5, \omega^7 \}$?

Comment: Those are the correct subfields. Well done! Which corresponds to which subgroup? Hint: $\sigma_{11}$ is the complex conjugation. Why? You are overthinking the basis. That set won't work. $\omega^6=-1$, so $\omega$ and $\omega^7$ are negatives of each other (and hence linearly dependent).

Comment: Is the basis simply given by $\{1, \sqrt{3}, i, \sqrt{3}i \}$? I'm still unaware as to how to determine what automorphisms fix certain subfields.

Comment: My thoughts are: first we see that $\omega_{12} = \frac{\sqrt{3}+i}{2}$ and thus $\sqrt{3}$ and $i$ are fixed by the automorphism sending $\omega_{12} \mapsto \omega_{12}$. This automorphism corresponds to $\mathbb{Q}(\omega_{12})$. Now, if we look at $\omega_{12}^5 = \frac{i-\sqrt{3}}{2}$, we see that $i$ is fixed by the automorphism sending $\omega_{12} \mapsto \omega_{12}^5$. Thus, this automorphism corresponds to $\mathbb{Q}(i)$.

Comment: Similarly the automorphism sending $\omega_{12} \mapsto \omega_{12}^7$ fixes $\mathbb{Q}$ and the automorphism sending $\omega_{12} \mapsto \omega_{12}^{11}$ fixes $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$.